# Setting up freshly installed Ubuntu 19.04 to send out mail with PHP application

Tags: email, webserver, mail, mail-server

I have a brand new ubuntu 19.04 install and I want to send emails from it via my PHP application. What software should I use if I want to send it from my server? And what software would I need if I wanted to use an external mail server? I'm just worried that this server's emails would be marked as spam. Anyway to reduce this risk?

Comment: If you are not sending lots of emails, and if the emails you are sending is not unsolicited, then your server probably won't be black-holed. But this question would be better located at some of the "server" sites.

Comment: What software do you recommend? From google it seems many people install postfix?

Comment: Hi, did you see that arrow ("This comment adds something useful to the post") and the flag on the side of comments? Did you consider, why it would be (not) good to use them? This is a social site in a way. You receive, you give. Also, what's your opinion about this part of my comment: "But this question would be better located at some of the "server" sites."?